# Speed up fastlane on CI

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, fastlane, bitrise

I don't understand why the same fastlane lanes take so much more time when they are running on Bitrise. I'm looking for a hint how to speed it up.

**Local machine:**

[image]

**On Bitrise:**

[image]

Lanes:

**pod_lib_lint:**

```rb
pod_lib_lint(
   podspec: podspec_path[PODSPEC_PATH_KEY],
   include_podspecs: podspec_path[PODSPEC_DEPENDENCIES_KEY],
   sources: PODS_SOURCES,
   skip_tests: true,
   allow_warnings: true
)
```

**run_tests:**

```rb
run_tests(
   output_types: 'junit,html',
   code_coverage: true,
   workspace: WORKSPACE_PATH,
   scheme: scheme,
   devices: TEST_DEVICES,
   output_directory: "#{SCAN_PATH}/#{kit}/#{scheme}",
   buildlog_path: "#{ENV['SECRET']}",
   derived_data_path: "#{DERIVED_DATA_PATH}/#{kit}/#{scheme}",
   prelaunch_simulator: true,
   xcargs: "COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO"
)
```

Im using Bitrise's cache pull/push:

```
    - cache-push:
        run_if: ".IsCI"
        inputs:
        - cache_paths: |
            $BITRISE_CACHE_DIR
            $GEM_CACHE_PATH
            ./Pods -> ./Podfile.lock
```

Comment: Because Bitrise VMs are likely less powerful than your local machine (their standard macOS machine is *"2xCPU (Intel Xeon E5-2697 v2) / 4 GB RAM"*) and don't have e.g. XCode's cache? See e.g. https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/ios-builds-slow-any-solution-to-speed-it-up/61

Comment: yes, try their `Elite Machine` plan and see if it's better. I bet it will be.

Comment: actually, it is "elite" :(